# How to do pagination of text in Android TextView

Tags: android, text, pagination, textview

I have long data that I want to see in `TextView`. I am trying to work on pagination with the following code:

```
TextPaint textPaint = tv.getPaint();
int boundedWidth = tv.getWidth();

StaticLayout layout = new StaticLayout(data, textPaint, boundedWidth , Alignment.ALIGN_NORMAL, 1.0f, 1, false);
layout.draw(new Canvas());

int totalLines = layout.getLineCount();
int currentPageNum = 0;
int topLine = 0;
int bottomLine = 0;

topLine = layout.getLineForVertical( currentPageNum * height );
bottomLine = layout.getLineForVertical( (currentPageNum + 1) * height );

int pageOffset = layout.getLineStart(topLine);
int pageEnd = layout.getLineEnd(bottomLine);

tv.setText(data.subSequence(pageOffset, pageEnd));
```

But `pageoffset` and `pageend` give me `startline+1` and `endline+1` value not exact offset of text which should be drawn.

What is wrong with my code? Is there any other way ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally i have make it work. My boundedWidth was zero so that why it was returning false data.